# Bad width calculation in Qcombobox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want a combobox with width adjusted to its (longest) content, so I use `AdjustToContents`. However, at least with my settings and the Oxygen style, I sometimes get a too short box and the contents are clipped. This seems to happen especially with digits:

[image]

Note that the `8` at the end is clipped. If I comment out that item, the length looks ok.

Is it a bug? Is there an easy way to fix it maybe with stylesheets or subclassing?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class HelloWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        gridLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)

        label = QLabel("Name")

        combobox = QComboBox()
        combobox.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox.AdjustToContents)
        combobox.addItem("Short")
        combobox.addItem("Longer text")
        combobox.addItem("abcdefghijklmnopqr")
        combobox.addItem("123456789012345678")

        gridLayout.addWidget(label)
        gridLayout.addWidget(combobox)
        gridLayout.addStretch(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = HelloWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: Hi, @Jellby. Which SO are you using?

Comment: @EliakinCosta Kubuntu 18.04... Interesting, I just tried on another computer (with the same SO and Qt style), and it works fine here. There must be some offending setting or version difference somewhere. Still, I shouldn't be getting the wrong width...

Comment: Try updating PyQt, it maybe solves this issue, @Jellby.

Comment: I've tested on Windows, OSX and Arch Linux and your code is working just fine. I'm using `PyQt5 5.13.2`. @Jellby

Comment: I think that the problem is not the version of Qt/PyQt or the OS since for example I reproduce the problem in archlinux, I think the problem is caused by the style

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
combobox = QComboBox(self)
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the culprit. I had the "Force fonts DPI" option in [KDE fonts settings](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/fonts/index.html) enabled and set to 96 (while `xdpyinfo | grep resolution` says 101 dpi). Disabling the option makes it work fine with all styles I have available (Breeze, Oxygen, Windows, Fusion).

Now, is this a KDE bug, a Qt bug or just a limitation?